# Get Facebook offsite conversion values

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to get the insights of an adset using. From the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.8), I understand that the field `cost_per_action_type` should contain the values for `offsite_conversion`. But, it doesn't return any offsite_conversion values.

This is request I've made:

```
2.8/<adset_id>/insights?fields=cpc,cpm,cost_per_action_type,cost_per_total_action,total_action_value,actions&action_attribution_windows=7d_view,28d_click
```

And this is the response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "cpc": "0.00452",
      "cpm": "0.284469",
      "cost_per_action_type": [
        {
          "action_type": "comment",
          "value": "0.048382",
          "7d_view": "37.98",
          "28d_click": "0.048444"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_reaction",
          "value": "0.011615",
          "7d_view": "0.575455",
          "28d_click": "0.011854"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "page_engagement",
          "value": "0.005765",
          "7d_view": "0.566866",
          "28d_click": "0.005824"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_engagement",
          "value": "0.005776",
          "7d_view": "0.566866",
          "28d_click": "0.005835"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "like",
          "value": "3.165",
          "28d_click": "3.165"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "link_click",
          "value": "0.015352",
          "28d_click": "0.015352"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post",
          "value": "0.808085",
          "28d_click": "0.808085"
        }
      ],
      "cost_per_total_action": "0.005765",
      "total_action_value": "0",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "comment",
          "value": "785",
          "7d_view": "1",
          "28d_click": "784"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_reaction",
          "value": "3270",
          "7d_view": "66",
          "28d_click": "3204"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "page_engagement",
          "value": "6588",
          "7d_view": "67",
          "28d_click": "6521"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_engagement",
          "value": "6576",
          "7d_view": "67",
          "28d_click": "6509"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "like",
          "value": "12",
          "28d_click": "12"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "link_click",
          "value": "2474",
          "28d_click": "2474"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post",
          "value": "47",
          "28d_click": "47"
        }
      ],
      "date_start": "2016-11-12",
      "date_stop": "2016-12-11"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

I am very well familiar with the Facebook's Graph API but not much familiar with ads part. Please help!

Comment: Did you check Facebook's Adverts Manager to confirm there actually are some conversions and that they do have value? Offsite conversions are typically reported using FB pixels and have specific event. In the API they are reported under composite action name like `offsite_conversion:fb_pixel_purchase`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. Have you confirmed that the campaign you're querying is in fact tracking an Offline Event Set, and that the Event Set has events from people to whom your campaign has delivered impressions recently?